# Download large data from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am downloading a pdf file(250 mb) from the server. When i save to it document directory. It is corrupted have size 1 kb only.

I am using the code for this:

```
if (!networkQueue) {
    networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];
}
UIProgressView *myProgressIndicatorImg;;
[networkQueue setDelegate:self];
[networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:myProgressIndicatorImg];
[networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
[networkQueue bytesDownloadedSoFar];
[networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[networkQueue setRequestDidReceiveResponseHeadersSelector :@selector(requestRecieved:)];


ASIHTTPRequest *request;

request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"example.com"]];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"E_governance"];
NSLog(@"E_governance media path is %@",dataPath);
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder



NSString *savePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",dataPath,@"Filename1.mp3"];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:savePath];
[request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"request1" forKey:@"name"]];

[networkQueue addOperation:request];
[networkQueue go];
```

Can anyone let me know where i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `ASINetworkQueue`?  Provide a link or tag the question appropriately (including `objective-c`).

Answer (score 3):

`ASIHTTP` is a *very* old framework that goes back to iOS 4.0. When it was up to date, it was great to use - I used it myself in many projects. However even with all the flags for the compiler, it just remains *far* behind the competition - [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). If your project is not large, consider switching - it has a completion handler and is much more modern than the procedural concept of `ASIHTTP`.

In case you are not able to switch - it is hard to determine where exactly your code goes south, but that `networkQueue` looks very suspicious, as you're not assigning it to neither `_networkQueue` nor `self.networkQueue` which would indicate that it is an instance variable and it may not be true. Make sure you're not initializing the queue just in the method, which would ultimately disappear after the method is done (considering the fact, that `ASIHTTP` is asynchronous, it would make sense, that only 1kb would get downloaded in that period of time).

Also - `ASIHTTP` is signal slot pattern driven (observer) - there are delegate methods for the queue to implement to see what is going on (`requestDidStartSelector`, `requestDidFinishSelector`).